# distinguish between number and letters in an Edit text

Tags: java, android

I want the user to tap on an Edit text operations, such as 1+3-5 then he/she press for long to get the result? my issue is that how can I let the app differentiates between numbers and operations(+,-,*)?

Comment: I am trying to create a simple calculator, the user should enter 3+7+5 then long press and the app should presents the result on the EditText.

Comment: you should use the regular expression I'm trying a method to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use code like this.

```
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String foo = "(40+2)*10";
    try {
        System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but be aware that this method doesn't follow the presence of mathematical operations.

but this [library](http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/) or [that](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx) do.

for further reading take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form).

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try them on and post again the final outcome.